# How to get nginx/1.3.14 working as proxy with nodejs and socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, socket.io

I have a nginx server serving all my static content for a webapp.
The app makes use of websockets implemented in node.js unsing socket.io. The node.js Backend is listening on port 8000.

If I include the socket-io.js file via port 8000 inside the static delivered documents everything works fine but I've read something about to use nginx as a proxy handling the port 8000 internal

So I#ve build a config like these:

```
server {

 server_name domain.com;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/domaim.com.log;
 location / {
    root /home/app/static/;
 }

 location /socket/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
 }
}
```

Then an access to socket.io through domain.com/socket/ is possible 
(get the message Welcome to socket.io).
Also the static content is delivered
But I cant find any way to load the "socket.io/socket.io.js" file via port 80.

Is that possible on a clean way?

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing 2 things: serving the static JS file being part of socket.io, versus passing the socket.io connection back to node.js running the socket.io backend. You should serve the socket.io client files like any other JS files.

Comment: @Code Painters THX first. Made some changes (embed the js in my static folder). But the strange is when I connect io.connect('http://domain.com/socket');  socket.io seems to change the url to http://domain.com/socket.io and then it fails again. So I changed th location to socket.io and now it works (But why is socket.io client using an different url to connect as the given one?)

Comment: @CodePainters Kindly have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103241/how-to-redirect-web-sockets-connection-through-nginx . i am very much stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `socket.connect(url, {resource:'socket'})`

The default resource is `socket.io`

https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO